# Organizing VBOs and Optimizing Calls to glDrawArrays()

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to figure out the pros and cons of different techniques in OpenGL.  The tutorials I'm reading suggest a performance hit on rendering lots of VBOs, and I'm inferring that one approach might be to store several objects in a single VBO.

Are there any good rules-of-thumb on how/why to organize and render data?  For a modern videogame, say for example "Modern Warfare", and if I'm looking at a scene with a sky background, several static buildings, lots of debris, and 10 NPCs, how many VBOs do you think they've created, and how many calls to glDrawArrays() do you think they're making?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw calls aren't the most expensive things; I believe it's common to have 100 ~ 1000 draw calls per frame.

An important thing for performance is reducing state changes. IIRC program change > texture change > buffer change. Sort your draw calls in order to switch stuff as rarely as possible.

Using one large VBO instead of several smaller ones might be beneficial for performance, but probably not the first thing I'd try.

Comment: Where does the VAO fit in this hierarchy of costs?  I'd imagine it's like switching buffers, since that's pretty much what it does.

Comment: I've heard that switching VAOs did marginally slower than using only one VAO and rebinding the buffers as necessary. But this could be old news now

Comment: Do you know of any resources which discuss data organization re VBOs?  For example, if I'm doing a chessgame, I might create 7 VBOs:  One each for board grid, pawn, bishop, rook, knight, queen and king.  Or I might create 33 VBOs to hold each piece along with the entire board.  (Or 1 VBO to hold the entire kit and kaboodle.)  Apart from guides which say more or less that "VBOs are preferred to client-side data," I haven't found anything which talks about this aspect of things.  Are there any tutorials or examples on this subject?

Comment: VBOs are just chunks of allocated memory, think `glBufferData` = `malloc` + `memcpy`. The question here is "how to arrange my data in GPU memory", with details like "whether to interleave the attributes or not". Try [OpenGL wiki: Vertex Specification Best Practices](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification_Best_Practices).